# jquery - which object of the whole set it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if there is an easy way to figure out which dom object i have considering it is also in another set of objects. Lets have an example:

I have 5 divs:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2" class="abc"></div>
<div id="3" class="abc"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5" class="abc"></div>
```

Now, i want to know which (first, second, fifth and so on) div with id="5" is in the set of divs with class="abc".
It would work like this:

```
var result = $('#5').which('.abc') => 3
var result = $('#5').which('div') => 5
```

Is that possible without looping and comparing names?

To be more clear i want to make something oposite to nth-child, because nth-child need N as parameter, i want to have this N calculated.

Comment: Only one element can have a given ID. Meaning, only one element can have an ID of "5". Do you mean given a set of divs, you want to get the index of the one which has an ID of "5"?

Comment: Not sure, but you might use the index method for this: `$( ".abc" ).index( $('#5') )` http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: `console.log($('#5').hasClass('abc'))` you can check the div's class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function (where the result is zero-based):

```js
console.log( $('#5').index('div.abc') )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2" class="abc"></div>
<div id="3" class="abc"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5" class="abc"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect - that's it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible pure js solution.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
    res = Array.from(elems).indexOf(Array.from(elems).find((v,i) => v.id == 5));
    
    console.log(res);
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2" class="abc"></div>
<div id="3" class="abc"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5" class="abc"></div>
```